# Programatic constraints with UISegmentedControl not working

Tags: ios, uikit, constraints

I am trying to use UIKit programatic constraints to create a simple interface where there is a row with a UISegmentedControl on the left and a yellow UIView on the right.

The problem is that I would like that UIView to extend for the full height of the view however for some reason its bottom anchor is not at the actual bottom of the segment controller.

[image]

Here is the code

```
parentGuide = top.layoutMarginsGuide

let choices = UISegmentedControl(items: ["Op1", "Op2"])
choices.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
top.addSubview(choices)
choices.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
choices.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true

let yellow = UIView()
yellow.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
top.addSubview(yellow)
yellow.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
yellow.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
yellow.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
yellow.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -40).isActive = true
yellow.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: choices.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
yellow.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: choices.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

make it

```
yellow.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: choices.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```